# If condition not working with DateTime entries

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am not able to get the correct report with the below part of code.
Here's what I am doing:

1. Importing .csv file into variable which contains `UserName`, `LastSucessSync` (date), `Model`.
2. With below `foreach` loop this will format the .html report and provide the values Green or Red.

Issue is, when Date is blank in .csv file it still shows GREEN or some times RED.
It also throws the below error:

```
Cannot convert value "" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not
recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\MobileStats.ps1:87 char:4
+ if([datetime]$Entry.LastSuccessSync -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) -or $Entry.LastS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider
```

Rest of all is fine. Just I want to mark it as RED when date is blank or 14 days before.

PowerShell Code:

```
foreach ($Entry in $Result) {
    if ([datetime]$Entry.LastSuccessSync -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) -or $Entry.LastSuccessSync -like "") {
        $Cdrivecolor="RED"
    } else {
        $Cdrivecolor="Green"
    }
```

Comment: It's telling you that the value of `$Entry.LastSuccessSync` is an empty string. Start by testing if that's the case (`if(-not($Entry.LastSuccessSync) -or ...)`)

Comment: or simply `if (!$Entry.LastSuccessSync -or ...)`

Comment: @Mathias. Brilliant. Thanks a Ton :) It worked like a charm.

Comment: @4c74356b41. Thanks. another way of doing right things ;) Cheers.